# Grails unschedule a quartz job

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I have a requirement to schedule and unschedule a quartz job programmatically. I was able to schedule it using `MyJob.schedule(cronExpression)`. Is there a way to similarly unschedule the job?

I am using quartz plugin `0.4.2` with Grails `1.2.3`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`removeJob()` removes the job altogether and it cannot be scheduled again programmatically with `MyJob.schedule(Trigger)`

Here is what worked for me,

```
quartzScheduler.unscheduleJob("TriggerName", "TriggerGroup")
//TriggerName and TriggerGroup are the name and group of the Trigger used for schedule
```

Comment: This is a silly question probably, but how did you get the TriggerName and TriggerGroup out of MyJob.schedule?

Answer (score 1):

QuartzGrailsPlugin.groovy says it's `removeJob()`.

Answer (score 0):

Running version 1.0.1

See this http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPQUARTZ-132#comment-78800

The trigger name by default on the MyJob.schedule() is screwy hardceoded UUID "GRAILS_586eb149-83f7-486c-88fc-e44a5bb0541" & a static group value of "GRAILS_TRIGGERS"

Either 
A: lookup your triggerName by the cronvalue (assuming it's unique) 
B: don't use the simple MyJob.schedule( trig) simple coolness provided by grails plugin.