# Disable Grails Quartz Job and start it in controller

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler, jobs

I using Quartz plugin in Grails. But I have some problems. Please help me!

I wants to disable Quartz Job in Grails at applications starting-up and wants to active it in controller and stop it later. I wants to active it in another controller.

Answer (score 4):

To disable Quartz from starting up, you can set the autostart to off explained [here](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-quartz/guide/configuration.html).

```
quartz {
    autoStartup = false
    ...
 }
```

To control the jobs you can define a job and trigger it manually through your application. Here is a blog describing it [here](http://pjava.wordpress.com/2013/02/01/grails-quartz-job-set-up-manually-with-start-and-stop/).  This article is defining the job through a service which is very flexible and handy and allow you to stop and start it. You can also schedule a job and unscheduling it as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514962/grails-unschedule-a-quartz-job)